# $8$ linear equations and $9$ unknowns can we solve?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Here are the equations:
\begin{align}
& A+B+C=15 \tag{1} \\
& P+Q+R=15 \tag{2} \\
& X+Y+Z=15 \tag{3} \\
& A+Q+Z=15 \tag{4} \\
& C+Q+X=15 \tag{5} \\
& A+P+X=15 \tag{6} \\
& B+Q+Y=15 \tag{7} \\
& C+R+Z=15 \tag{8}
\end{align}
Also, provide the method in detail to solve these equations

Thanks!

**Edit 1**: These equations are $3 \times 3$ square, where each row/column/diagonal sum to $15$.

**Edit 2**: All unknowns are unique from 1 to 9.

Comment: 8 equations, more than 8 unknowns. In general, you have one degree of freedom.

Comment: Do you know how to solve two equations in two unknowns?  Have you seen that with three unknowns and two equations you usually have one that can be chosen arbitrarily?  More equations and more unknowns is just more of the same work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for adding some context to your Question.  Perhaps you are interested in assigning different integer values to the unknowns, so that values $1$ through $9$ are each used exactly once?

Comment: Thx for reply, yes @hardmath

Comment: Now added total clues to the question!

Comment: It seems likely that equation (5) is misstated and should be $C+Q+X=15$.

Comment: yes @hardmath, I found solution by trial error method, but I need proper way to solve any of these kind problems.

Comment: At this point you might want to research what is already known about "these kind of problems" ([magic squares](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)).  The $3\times 3$ solution is unique up to rotation and reflection, the symmetries of a square.  Much was previously said about [tag:magic-square] on Math.SE.

Comment: @hardmath Amazing to see you, even after 5 years you are replying.
Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the symmetry of the problem (each equation is the sum of three variables equals $15$), one solution is $$A=B=C=P=Q=R=X=Y=Z=5$$

There are infinitely many solutions, however, as the number of variables exceeds the number of equations.

---

Update, due to edits.  Subtracting equation (5) from (4) yields $A-C=0$, or $A=C$.  Hence it is impossible for the nine variables to each stand for distinct values from $1$ to $9$.

Comment: edited eqn 5  to make it clear.